# Is there way to fix below mentioned error in angular 17 (ssr enabled)?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

Tried to build angular 17 project but encountered error:

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Core/Utilities.js') which is preventing from building the project.

I used command `npx ng build --configuration production` to build the project

[image: Build issue image with angular version details]

Comment: Are you using HighCharts ? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/235

Comment: Yes i am using highcharts ( "highcharts": "^11.4.0",  "highcharts-angular": "^4.0.0")

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't support SSR.

You have to make it run client side only:
This is what the [docs recommends](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#angular-universal--SSR):

```
export class AppComponent {
  isHighcharts = typeof Highcharts === 'object';
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {...};
}
<highcharts-chart
  *ngIf="isHighcharts"
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
></highcharts-chart>
```